# showing the drift chat widget for a particular page in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have a word press website in which i am planning to show the drift chat window for a particular page only but the issue with the code is when i put the drift chat code in the header.php then it shows in the entire website at the footer. But my objective is to display that chat widget in a particular page not the entire site.

In header.php i placed this code.

```
<!-- Start of Async Drift Code -->
<script>
"use strict";

!function() {
 var t = window.driftt = window.drift = window.driftt || [];
 if (!t.init) {
   if (t.invoked) return void (window.console && console.error && console.error("Drift snippet included twice."));
   t.invoked = !0, t.methods = [ "identify", "config", "track", "reset", "debug", "show", "ping", "page", "hide", "off", "on" ],
   t.factory = function(e) {
     return function() {
       var n = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
       return n.unshift(e), t.push(n), t;
     };
   }, t.methods.forEach(function(e) {
     t[e] = t.factory(e);
   }), t.load = function(t) {
     var e = 3e5, n = Math.ceil(new Date() / e) * e, o = document.createElement("script");
     o.type = "text/javascript", o.async = !0, o.crossorigin = "anonymous", o.src = "https://js.driftt.com/include/" + n + "/" + t + ".js";
     var i = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
     i.parentNode.insertBefore(o, i);
   };
 }
}();
drift.SNIPPET_VERSION = '0.3.1';
drift.load('963auir3rcg6');
</script>
<!-- End of Async Drift Code -->
```

How can i achieve it?

Any suggestions on it?

Comment: just use `if(is_page(2)){` condition

Comment: @Vel where should i use this condition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this code in header.php

```
<?php

    if(is_page(2)){

?>

    <!-- Start of Async Drift Code -->
    <script>
        "use strict";

        !function() {
         var t = window.driftt = window.drift = window.driftt || [];
         if (!t.init) {
           if (t.invoked) return void (window.console && console.error && console.error("Drift snippet included twice."));
           t.invoked = !0, t.methods = [ "identify", "config", "track", "reset", "debug", "show", "ping", "page", "hide", "off", "on" ],
           t.factory = function(e) {
             return function() {
               var n = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
               return n.unshift(e), t.push(n), t;
             };
           }, t.methods.forEach(function(e) {
             t[e] = t.factory(e);
           }), t.load = function(t) {
             var e = 3e5, n = Math.ceil(new Date() / e) * e, o = document.createElement("script");
             o.type = "text/javascript", o.async = !0, o.crossorigin = "anonymous", o.src = "https://js.driftt.com/include/" + n + "/" + t + ".js";
             var i = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
             i.parentNode.insertBefore(o, i);
           };
         }
        }();
        drift.SNIPPET_VERSION = '0.3.1';
        drift.load('963auir3rcg6');
    </script>
    <!-- End of Async Drift Code -->

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Hey Vel, thanks for this code but the issue is one page is not working showing the empty page. also what is the meaning of passing parameter 2 in is_page(2)

Comment: 2 is page id.You can pass array like  `if(is_page(array(2,5,6,7,8,9)) )`

Comment: With the code you provides one of the page is broken https://test.domain.io/about-us-2/pricing/ and rest of the website is working fine. Why the wired behavior

Comment: can you post your actual code and what is the page is for pricing page?